# Change default printer per-website

Tags: mac, firefox, osx-snow-leopard, printer

I have two printers.  When printing from Firefox, I would like the proper printer to be selected by default.

- Zebra 5"x4" thermal label printer: default printer *for UPS.com websites only*
- Brother standard A4 (8.5"x11") laser printer:  default printer for any other website

Is it possible to change my default printer when printing from a particular website in Firefox?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to script it, you can set the default printer through the registry: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/102966 - and you can probably use AutoIt or something like python or perl to detect the url you are on and set default printer as necessary. I'll see if I can figure out a working method.

Comment: @MaQleod:  Thanks for the feedback.  I'm on a Mac, so the registry edits wont do the trick.

Comment: Unless there is an obscure Firefox extension, this is impossible.

Comment: it is possible, just change the requirement of number of pages to another recognition: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03RbCbBkAL8 but this is a windows, solution not mac...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac, you'll want to use [Applescript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript), it can automate a LOT for you.

[This](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021011062202259) will let you set the default printer as needed - you'll need to run that based off of what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263741/using-applescript-to-grab-the-url-from-the-frontmost-window-in-web-browsers-the) tells you for what url firefox is currently on. You'll probably need some parsing to just get the domain.tld out of the url to determine where to print, but that should get you pointed in the right direction.